# Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I got the following problem after updating the Gradle. I was not able to find any solution for it.
So please help me to solve the following problem.
Thanks in advance...

(PROBLEM-----Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'. Received status code 406 from server: Not Acceptable)

My build.gradle file...

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you have proper internet connection while syncing gradle files. Also ensure Gradle offline build is turned off in settings

Comment: I have proper internet connection and also my Gradle offline build is turned off in settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set build.gradle(project level)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

and in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

then sync again project.

Answer (score 0):

Android Gradle plugin 4.1.0 is not release yet. see on [Google's Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.android.tools.build:gradle). Try `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-rc02'` if you want to use 4.1.0.

Comment: even the Android Gradle plugin 4.0.1 is not working

Comment: Which version of Gradle do you use? See it in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`